# ActionController::UnknownFormat in Rails as API Show Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm getting below error when I navigate to `site.io/#/users/1/quizzes/1`

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/quizzes_controller.rb:7:in `show'
```

And the console displays a `406 not acceptable` error

**My Thoughts**
I suspect there is something wrong with `respond_with user, quiz` but the error is so unspecific I'm unable to figure out what is wrong.

**Quizzes Controller** <-- SHOW ACTION DOES NOT WORK

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @quiz = @user.quizzes.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @user, @quiz
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :quizzes do
    resources :questions
  end
end
```

It's strange that I'm getting an error with the `Show` action because a very similar `Create` action works fine.

**Quizzes Controller** <-- CREATE ACTION WORKS

```
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @quiz = @user.quizzes.create(quiz_params)
    respond_with @user, @quiz
end
```

I've spent several hours trying to figure this out. It likely comes from my lack of understanding of responding with JSON. Any advice would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Try adding , :defaults => { :format => 'json' } to your route

Answer (score 0):

your code seems fine to me. I am not really familiar with `respond_with` and also that it is working one time seems a bit odd.
But maybe this code snippet can help you.

Add this line to `application/controller/application_controller.rb`

```
respond_to :json
```

Now your responder will apply the format to json for all actions. You can also specify it per controller. Whatever suits you best.

Then  change your `show` method to

```
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   @quiz = @user.quizzes.find(params[:id])
   render json: {user: @user, quiz: @quiz}, status: :ok
end
```

and you will receive an hash like this:

```
{"user":{"id":1,"name":"foo","phone":"123","address":"baa","created_at":"2016-03-30T08:30:42.586Z","updated_at":"2016-03-30T08:30:42.586Z"},"quiz":{"id":2,...}}
```